# Store Shipping Method Changes if Shipping and Billing Details Don't Match

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

Using Store 1.6.3
I have only two shipping methods: Collect in store (free), or UK flat delivery fee of £4 per order. When a customer chooses the delivery fee, but then unticks the Shipping Details are the Same as Billing Details, and adds a different shipping address, the method name doesn't change, but the value goes to zero (should stay £4)! I have tested this myself using two UK addresses and sure enough, the total reverts back to £4 once my shipping and billing addresses match. 
The live site: http://www.thirstymeeples.co.uk/

Any ideas what causes this? Thanks!

[image: Shipping Methods]
[image: Shipping Method]
[image: Shipping Rule]

Comment: Why is the flat fee shipping method restricted to only the UK? If you make it match any country, does the problem persist?

Comment: That solves the problem, Adrian, thanks! I had it restricted to the UK because we want to accept payment from orders placed outside of the country, but delivery is restricted to the UK. I see there are other ways of handling this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, one option is to remove the country restriction (UK) from the UK Delivery Flat Fee rule.

Because you aren't offering shipping outside the UK anyway, there's no need to restrict the shipping rule to UK only (since when no rules match the cart it is displaying $0 shipping).

In Store 1, generally if no shipping rules for the currently selected shipping method match the current cart, an error will be displayed. In Store 2, if no rules match the current cart then the shipping method is not even displayed.